# I don't understand 'closest()' still... Please clarify

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am struggling with jQuery's **closest()** selector.

[I've made a jsfiddle of what I think *should* work](http://jsfiddle.net/uRgEw/1/)... but it clearly doesn't. Why not?

the HTML

```
<div class="button">button</div>
<div class="return_window"></div>
```

and the incredibly complex JS

```
$('.button').click(function(){

    $(this).closest('.return_window').html('hi');

});
```

What don't I understand about this illusive .closest() selector?? Those div's look pretty close to me. I've read the documentation but I don't know what it is.. Resig's documentation or whoever writes it seems to be on a different dimension to me.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) says: *"Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree."* `.return_window` is not an ancestor.

Comment: Thanks Felix. The terminology I find a bit confusing... ancestors... parents etc etc has always for some reason seemed odd to me. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yeah, after reading your question again, I noticed that you mentioned that you read the docs. I [created a simple image](http://felix-kling.de/images/DOM_relationship.png) which tries to explain the relationship between DOM nodes. Once you learned this, you can use this knowledge in other DOM related areas as well, e.g. XPath. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for that image. Very helpful Felix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

closest looks up the DOM, if the start point is not inside the one you are looking for it wont find it.

I modded your code to show this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uRgEw/2/

maybe you are looking for this:

```
$('.button').click(function(){

alert('hi');

$(this).closest('.container').find('.return_window').html('hi');

});
```

with HTML of:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="return_window">

    </div>
    <div class="button">button</div>
</div>
```

this will let you go up and back down with a good degree of flexibility.

as done here:

http://jsfiddle.net/uRgEw/5/

Comment: I like that. It goes outward to the container, then finds the thing inside. Makes sense. Cheers.

Comment: You are very welcome, I probably not the fastest but I use this type of thing a lot as its not so likely to break with modifications.

Answer (score 4):

`closest` is used to climb up the DOM tree, rather than look sideways at sibling elements. In simple terms, it will look at the parent element, and the parent of that, and so on, until it reaches what it's looking for (or the top of the DOM tree).

For example:

```
<div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
        <div id="child"></div>
        <div class="grandparent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following jQuery will select the outer `div`, rather than the sibling `div`:

```
$(".child").closest(".grandparent");
```

`closest` is the opposite of [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), which looks *down* the DOM tree. To select siblings, you can use the [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method.

Comment: I would more consider `parents()` as opposite to `find()`, but you are right of course.

Comment: Hmm yes I suppose you're right :) `closest` is *almost* the opposite of `find`, but `parents` is a better fit.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could do `.find(...).first()`.

Answer (score 1):

Closest searches *PARENTS* of the element - not siblings near the elements.

It's called closest because it finds the closest parent of a particular type (selector) to the element. The `.parents()` get all the parents.

I use it all the time.

Like:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <p>
      <input type="button" onClick="alert($(this).closest('form'));">
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

From deep inside I can quickly find the parent form, ignoring all the intervening elements.

If you want the nearest sibling do:

```
$(this).prevAll('.return_window').last();
$(this).nextAll('.return_window').first();
```

This will give you the two closest siblings above and below, and it's on you to figure out which is closer.

Answer (score 1):

In your case use next() not closest() as closest() looks up the tree BEGINNING with the current element:

```
$('.button').click(function(){

    $(this).next('.return_window').html('hi');

});
```

Comment: NEXT!! that seems pretty basic.

Comment: No, do not use `.next()` with a selector, the results will not be what you expect. Use `.nextAll('xxx').first()`. `.next()` with a selector does this: Find the next element, if it matches the selector return it. If not, return *nothing*! This always confuses people.

Comment: @Ariel of course i wanted to return something only if the selector is matched, that's why i use next with a selector. Your code does a different thing.

Comment: You code only returns something if the _very next_ element matches. The one right after. This is rarely what you want. If you really did want it, why are you including a selector? Just do `.next()` by itself. `.next()` with a selector is almost never what you want.

Comment: @Ariel I want to be sure that i modify the next element only if it's what i think it is. Otherwise of course i would use what you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

`.closest()` finds the closest *ancestor* that matches your selector. `closest()` starts with itself, then its parent, or its parents' parent, or so on.

what you have there are siblings. you should use `.siblings()` if you want to find elements that share the same parent, or are *next* to each other.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="return_window">
    <div class="button">button</div>
</div>
```

In your example the above would be the HTML that would work. It finds the closest ancestor.

You could use something like:

```
$(this).next('.return_window').html('hi')
```

With the HTML you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

closest walks from the current selected element to the root, using `parentNode`, and find the first element which matches the given selector:

```
function closest(element, selector) {
    while (element != null) {
        if (matchesSelector(element, selector)) {
            return true;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    return null;
}
```

For example, we have HTML like:

```
<div id="d1" class="a">
  <div id="d2" class="b">
    <div id="d3" class="a">
      <span id="target"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and we need some closest selector, the output would be:

- closest(target, '.a') -> #d3
- closest(target, 'div') -> #d3
- closest(target, '.b') -> #d2